# install Ubuntu using rufus(usb) fill system = ext 4 but after i log my windows 10 os it"s shown empty 2 NTFS partition ?

Tags: ext4

1) ext4 partition for Ubuntu = 100 gb
2) ext4 partition for swap = 10 gb

log windows os 
1)=empty NTFS 
2)=empty NTFS

but Ubuntu workig!! why my partition is empty??? and why NTFS??

Answer (score 1):

If I did not misunderstand the question, you ask why you do not see the ext4 partition in Windows. (Sorry if that's not what you're asking)
Windows does not bring native support for ext4, so it does not recognize it.

Comment: question is unclear ! sorry about that!

Comment: i have windows 10 operating system! and i install Ubuntu using usb! create two partition 1 for Ubuntu and 2 swap , next i install Ubuntu working ! but i load windows os and open my computer in their (before i using 1 and 2 partition showing like EMPTY NTFS partition ! but i use these partition for Ubuntu  )  why these partition showing on windows 10 os , and why ntfs , and why empty ???

Comment: I think the answer by user186255 is correct. "Windows 'does not want to understand' linux partitions ( with file systems and linux swap)" might be another way of explaining why it happens.